# Query content of two consecutive quarter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named evaluations. It have 4 column: user_id, quarter, year, content.

I want to select all field of two consecutive quarter(ex: current quarter is 2, so i want to select all field of quarter 1, year 2020 and quarter 4, year 2019)

This is my query:

```
SELECT e1.user_id, 
e1.quarter AS last_quarter, 
e1.year AS last_year, 
e1.content AS content_last_quarter, 
e2.quarter AS quarter, 
e2.year AS year, 
e2.content AS content_quarter 
FROM evaluations AS e1 JOIN evaluations AS e2 ON e2.user_id = e1.user_id
WHERE (e1.year = 2019) 
    AND (e1.quarter = 4) 
    AND (e2.year = 2020)) 
    AND (e2.quarter = 1) 
    AND e1.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND e2.deleted_at IS NULL
```

But if record of (quarter 1, year 2020) is exist, record of (quarter 4, year 2019) is empty or vice versa, then no result. I want to select if either or both exist. Can anyone help me?

Sorry that my English level is not good.

Thank you!

Comment: Your life would be much easier if you instead just used a single timestamp column instead of separate columns for quarter and year.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do not change the design of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT e.user_id, 
       MAX(e.quarter) FILTER (WHERE year = 2019) as last_quarter, 
       MAX(e.quarter) FILTER (WHERE year = 2019) as last_year, 
       MAX(e.content) FILTER (WHERE year = 2019) as last_content, 
       MAX(e.quarter) FILTER (WHERE year = 2020) as quarter, 
       MAX(e.quarter) FILTER (WHERE year = 2020) as year, 
       MAX(e.content) FILTER (WHERE year = 2020) as content
FROM evaluations e
WHERE ((e.year = 2019 AND e.quarter = 4) OR
       (e.year = 2020 AND e.quarter = 1) 
      ) AND
      e.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY e.user_id;
```

Comment: If the **content** is jsonb type (`content -> 'a' -> 'b'`), what should I do?

Comment: @user11742091 . . . Ask a new question.  That doesn't seem to be related to this question.

Comment: A, just `(content -> 'a' -> 'b')::text`. Thank you very much!